# How to efficiently cross reference 2 text files? | Improve my code

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, list, text-files

Below an outline of what my code does:

- Read TextFileA which has 150k lines.
- Read TextFileB which has 150k lines and is a cross reference list for TextFileA.
- .Split both text files and match specified elements.
- Finally, output a 3rd text file which will contain values from both TextFileA and TextFileB.

The below code runs well until about 13,000 lines in and then the program becomes exceedingly slow.

Could someone explain why the program becomes exponentially slower and how I could improve on this code? Thanks.

```
private void BT_Xref_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //grabs file path from text box
        string ManifestPath = TB_Manifest.Text;
        //grabs parent directory from file path
        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(ManifestPath);
        //creates a new folder for the final output text file
        string pathString = Path.Combine(directoryName, "Final Index");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
        //list for matching text lines which will eventually be output to the final text file
        List<string> NewData = new List<string>();

        //initializes StreamReader for the first text file
        StreamReader ManifestReader = new StreamReader(ManifestPath);
        String[] ManifestArray = File.ReadAllLines(ManifestPath);
        List<string> RemoveManifest = new List<string>(ManifestArray);
        //initializes StreamReader for the second text file
        StreamReader OutputReader = new StreamReader(TB_Complete.Text);
        String[] OutputArray = File.ReadAllLines(TB_Complete.Text);
        List<string> RemoveOutput = new List<string>(OutputArray);

        //initializes a count which decides at what point a text file should be created
        int shortcount = 0;
        //.ReadLine is initialized to ignore the first line in both text files
        string ManifestLine = ManifestReader.ReadLine();
        string OutputLine = OutputReader.ReadLine();

        foreach (string mfile in ManifestArray)
        {
            ManifestLine = ManifestReader.ReadLine();
            string ManifestElement = ManifestLine.Split(',')[6];
            string ManifestElement2 = ManifestLine.Split(',')[5];
            //value to be retreived and output to final text file
            string ManifestElementDate = ManifestElement2.Replace("/", "-");
            //value to be compared with the other text file
            string ManifestNoExt = Regex.Replace(ManifestElement, ("(\\.\\w+$)"),"");
            //resets OutpuReader reader to ensure no lines are being skipped
            OutputReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;

            //counting the mfile position in the ManifestArray
            //int removeIndex = Array.IndexOf(ManifestArray, mfile);
            //remove by resising the array
            //Array.Resize(ref ManifestArray, ManifestArray.Length - 1);

            foreach (string ofile in OutputArray)
            {
                OutputLine = OutputReader.ReadLine();
                //value to be comapred with other text file
                string OutputElement = OutputLine.Split('|')[2];
                //if values equal then add the specified line of text to the list.
                if (ManifestNoExt.Equals(OutputElement))
                {
                    NewData.Add(OutputLine + "|" + ManifestElementDate);
                    RemoveManifest.RemoveAll(item => item == ManifestLine);

                    if (NewData.Count == 1000)
                    {
                        //if youve reached the count then output files into a new text file
                        shortcount = shortcount + 1;
                        File.WriteAllLines(pathString + "\\test" + shortcount + ".txt", NewData);
                        NewData.Clear();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //once all line of text have been searched combine all text files in directory
        shortcount = shortcount + 1;
        File.WriteAllLines(pathString + "\\test" + shortcount + ".txt", NewData);
        String[] SplitTextFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pathString, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        using (var FinalIndexFile = File.Create(pathString + "\\FinalIndex.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var file in SplitTextFiles)
            {
                using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
                {
                    input.CopyTo(FinalIndexFile);
                }
                File.Delete(file);
            }
        }
        //File.WriteAllLines("\\test.txt", Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathString, @"*.txt").SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file)));
    }
```

Comment: You might want to rationalize your code (remove commented-out code, remove anything not pertinent to your question, etc.) into a stand-alone repro-case with example source data.

Comment: Also, what is NewData? It's not declared anywhere.

Comment: Have you run your code under a profiler? Have you measured memory consumption and file IO?

Comment: @rich Turner thanks for the response. I have not run it under a profiler. As for new data it is a list declared in the beginning. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have an O(nm) algorithm here, and assuming that n and m are the same, its actually an O(n^2). That's not so good and is why its slowing to a crawl (for 150k rows in each file, you are looking at 22500000000 iterations of the inner loop. Not entirely certain what your code is trying to do, but based on the condition `if (ManifestNoExt.Equals(OutputElement))`, I think you can reduce the complexity drastically as follows:

Read in TextFileA, store values into a Dictionary based on ManifestNoExt as Key and mFile as value.

Next read in TextFileB and iterate over all rows in B and do a lookup in the dictionary that was constructed.

This will give you an algorithm that is O(n) + O(m), which will be fast.

Also, I am not sure why you are reading in the entire files and then reading them in again inside the loops (the contents of ManifestArray and OutputArray is the same as the files). That is certainly a cause for slow down as well since you are going to end up hammering the file system.

A completely untested version of this idea:

```
private void BT_Xref_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //grabs file path from text box
    string ManifestPath = TB_Manifest.Text;
    //grabs parent directory from file path
    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(ManifestPath);
    //creates a new folder for the final output text file
    string pathString = Path.Combine(directoryName, "Final Index");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
    //list for matching text lines which will eventually be output to the final text file
    List<string> NewData = new List<string>();

    String[] ManifestArray = File.ReadAllLines(ManifestPath);
    List<string> RemoveManifest = new List<string>(ManifestArray);
    String[] OutputArray = File.ReadAllLines(TB_Complete.Text);
    List<string> RemoveOutput = new List<string>(OutputArray);

    //initializes a count which decides at what point a text file should be created
    int shortcount = 0;
    //.ReadLine is initialized to ignore the first line in both text files
    string ManifestLine = ManifestReader.ReadLine();
    string OutputLine = OutputReader.ReadLine();

    Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> ManifestMap = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();

    foreach (string mfile in ManifestArray.Skip(1))
    {
        string ManifestLine = mfile;
        string ManifestElement = ManifestLine.Split(',')[6];
        string ManifestElement2 = ManifestLine.Split(',')[5];
        //value to be retreived and output to final text file
        string ManifestElementDate = ManifestElement2.Replace("/", "-");
        //value to be compared with the other text file
        string ManifestNoExt = Regex.Replace(ManifestElement, ("(\\.\\w+$)"),"");

        ManifestMap.Add(ManifestNoExt, Tuple.Create(ManifestElementDate, ManifestLine));

        //counting the mfile position in the ManifestArray
        //int removeIndex = Array.IndexOf(ManifestArray, mfile);
        //remove by resising the array
        //Array.Resize(ref ManifestArray, ManifestArray.Length - 1);
    }

    foreach (string ofile in OutputArray.Skip(1))
    {
        //value to be compared with other text file
        string OutputElement = OutputLine.Split('|')[2];
        //if values equal then add the specified line of text to the list.
        if (ManifestMap.ContainsKey(OutputElement))
        {
            NewData.Add(OutputLine + "|" + ManifestMap[OutputElement].Item1);
            RemoveManifest.RemoveAll(item => item == ManifestMap[OutputElement].Item2);

            if (NewData.Count == 1000)
            {
                //if youve reached the count then output files into a new text file
                shortcount = shortcount + 1;
                File.WriteAllLines(pathString + "\\test" + shortcount + ".txt", NewData);
                NewData.Clear();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    //once all line of text have been searched combine all text files in directory
    shortcount = shortcount + 1;
    File.WriteAllLines(pathString + "\\test" + shortcount + ".txt", NewData);
    String[] SplitTextFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pathString, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    using (var FinalIndexFile = File.Create(pathString + "\\FinalIndex.txt"))
    {
        foreach (var file in SplitTextFiles)
        {
            using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                input.CopyTo(FinalIndexFile);
            }
            File.Delete(file);
        }
    }
    //File.WriteAllLines("\\test.txt", Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathString, @"*.txt").SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file)));
}
```

Comment: I was unfamiliar with Dictionary Tuple and spent the day implementing this for my purpose. It works incredibly well. Thanks so much for your response.